# SunOS 5.10 /bin/sh && changing env vars does not work

Tags: shell, export, sunos

When I change an env var in `/bin/sh`, it only takes effect after a new `export` command, for example:

```
$ which ant
/usr/sfw/bin/ant
$ env | grep ANT
ANT_HOME=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.8
$ PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ which ant 
/usr/sfw/bin/ant
$ env | egrep '^PATH='
PATH=/usr/local/gcc-492/bin:/export/home/sisis/mpi-V50:...
$ export PATH
$ which ant
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.8/bin/ant
$ env | egrep '^PATH='
PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.8/bin:/usr/local/gcc-492/bin:/export/home/sisis/mpi-V50 ...
```

Is this a bug or a new feature?

Matthias

Answer (score 3):

Feature. Not-exported variables are not visible to programs forked to. Export them to make them visible. `PATH` is inherited from the parent process, and will be passed on as-is to child processes such as `env`; only after being flagged with `export` will any changes in the shell process be visible to child processes. This can also be observed in the [heirloom bourne shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html):

```
$ PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin
$ env | grep \^PATH
PATH=/Users/jdoe/bin:/Users/jdoe/usr/darwin15.0-x86_64/bin:/Users/jdoe/perl5/bin:...
$ export PATH
$ env | grep \^PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
$ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ env | grep \^PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$
```

Modern (or even other) shells differ; ZSH for example exports `PATH` by default:

```
$ PS1='%% ' zsh -f
% echo ${(t)PATH}
scalar-export-special
%
```

However this different behavior has no influence on the SunOS `sh` or heirloom bourne `sh`.

Comment: The var PATH is in the env already as my posting shows (line 8+9).

Comment: @guru yes and that was inherited from the parent process. Only after `export` are local changes in the shell visible to child prcoesses.

Comment: I proved this on some other SunOS server and on FreeBSD: a change of the value of, for example, PATH is visible right away with `env | grep PATH` without an additional `export PATH`

Comment: @gure that only proves that different shells are different.

Comment: ofc they are; but this "feature" or bug I see for the 1st time after 25 years of UNIX; btw: in Linux bash a change to `PATH` is also visible after this with `env`